# I trying some ajax script without success, when I submit the form I take success alert but nothing send to the Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I trying some ajax script without success, when I submit the form I take success alert but nothing send to the Database.

My HTML form:

```
<form action="account_info.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Save"/>
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="Save"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

My PHP code:

```
$error='';
$info='';
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    require_once "classes/fields_process.php";
    require_once "classes/blocked_emails.php";

    if(!$usr->edit_info($crt_usr)) { 
        $usr_info=$usr->getTmp();
        $error=$usr->getError();
    } else { 
        $info=$usr->getInfo();
        $usr_info = $usr->getUser($crt_usr);
    }
} else $usr_info = $usr->getUser($crt_usr);

$smarty->assign("tmp",$usr_info);
$smarty->assign("error",$error);
$smarty->assign("info",$info);
```

Comment: what's the code on:    `fields_process.php` and `blocked_emails.php`

Comment: where is your jQuery code?

Comment: Is in the php file of the script i don't have a query i need an example to make the ajax call without refresh the page

Comment: This classes is ionqube encoded files

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the form : **"accountForm"**

```
<form action="account_info.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" **id="accountForm"**>
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Save"/>
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="Save"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
$.customPOST = function(data,callback){
    $.post('account_info.php',data,callback,'json');
}
$('#accountForm').submit(function(){
  $.customPOST($(this).serialize(),function(r){
   //the response from the server in JSON format
   //an array, example in the PHP script we return
   //an array that contains : 'success' => true
   if(r.sucess){
     alert('Operation OK');
   }
  });
  return false;
});
```

BUT in your PHP you need to echo the response in JSON format :

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
```

Comment: phpCore how can do this: echo json_encode(array('success' => true));

Comment: With your script it's impossible cause you use Smarty. You need to have a regular PHP script that ends with an ECHO

Comment: I use oxyclassifieds script

Answer (score 0):

Ok i resolve the problem.

```
<form name="accountform" id="accountform" method="post" action="account.php">
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Save"/>
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="Save"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"/>
</form>



{literal}<script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#accountform').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
  </script>{/literal}
```